# Support for interruptions in bot

Tags: azure, botframework

Do you know if there is way to implement global message handlers that can support commands like stop, bye, cancel, exit [Virtual assistant bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-virtual-assistant-introduction?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) ? I am trying to implement something like this.

I have a virtual assistant built already and it has couple of [Skills or Skill Bots.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-skills-overview?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) 
When user is in the multi turn conversation with a Skill, user should be able to exit out of skill by commands like stop, bye, cancel, exit.

I found old [v3 doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-global-handlers?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) but nothing for v4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the documentations provided here [Handling User Interruption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-handle-user-interrupt?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) They explain how to handle user interruption for SDK v4

Find below an example of how you can configure this in the **Virtual Assistant**.

In your **MainDialog.cs**

Add the following for your **OnContinueDialogAsync**: Keeping in mind that you can change and edit this as you see fit just **be sure to check the OnInterruptDialogAsync result** **(status in this example)** before you continue

```
  protected override async Task<DialogTurnResult> OnContinueDialogAsync(DialogContext innerDc, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var status = await OnInterruptDialogAsync(innerDc, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (status == InterruptionAction.Resume)
        {
            // Resume the waiting dialog after interruption
            await innerDc.RepromptDialogAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            return EndOfTurn;
        }
        else if (status == InterruptionAction.Waiting)
        {
            // Stack is already waiting for a response, shelve inner stack
            return EndOfTurn;
        }
        else
        {
            var activity = innerDc.Context.Activity;

            if (activity.IsStartActivity())
            {
                await OnStartAsync(innerDc).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }

            switch (activity.Type)
            {
                case ActivityTypes.Message:
                    {
                        // Note: This check is a workaround for adaptive card buttons that should map to an event (i.e. startOnboarding button in intro card)
                        if (activity.Value != null)
                        {
                            await OnEventAsync(innerDc).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var result = await innerDc.ContinueDialogAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                            switch (result.Status)
                            {
                                case DialogTurnStatus.Empty:
                                    {
                                        await RouteAsync(innerDc).ConfigureAwait(false);
                                        break;
                                    }

                                case DialogTurnStatus.Complete:
                                    {
                                        // End active dialog
                                        await innerDc.EndDialogAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                                        break;
                                    }

                                default:
                                    {
                                        break;
                                    }
                            }
                        }

                        // If the active dialog was ended on this turn (either on single-turn dialog, or on continueDialogAsync) run CompleteAsync method.
                        if (innerDc.ActiveDialog == null)
                        {
                            await CompleteAsync(innerDc).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        }

                        break;
                    }

                case ActivityTypes.Event:
                    {
                        //do something for event activity
                        break;
                    }

                case ActivityTypes.Invoke:
                    {
                        // Used by Teams for Authentication scenarios.

                        break;
                    }

                default:
                    {
                        await OnSystemMessageAsync(innerDc).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        break;
                    }
            }

            return EndOfTurn;
        }
    }
```

And override **OnInterruptDialogAsync** like below example:
This example includes **LUIS** but you can do whatever you want in **OnInterruptDialogAsync**

```
   protected override async Task<InterruptionAction> OnInterruptDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var result = InterruptionAction.NoAction;

        if (dc.Context.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(dc.Context.Activity.Text))
        {
            // get current activity locale
            var localeConfig = _services.GetCognitiveModels();

            // check general luis intent
            localeConfig.LuisServices.TryGetValue("General", out var luisService);

            if (luisService == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("The specified LUIS Model could not be found in your Skill configuration.");
            }
            else
            {
                var luisResult = await luisService.RecognizeAsync<GeneralLuis>(dc.Context, cancellationToken);
                var topIntent = luisResult.TopIntent();

                if (topIntent.score > 0.5)
                {
                    switch (topIntent.intent)
                    {
                        case GeneralLuis.Intent.Cancel:
                            {
                                result = await OnCancel(dc);
                                break;
                            }

                        case GeneralLuis.Intent.Help:
                            {
                                result = await OnHelp(dc);
                                break;
                            }

                        case GeneralLuis.Intent.Logout:
                            {
                                result = await OnLogout(dc);
                                break;
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: I had reviewed this but it is for a single v4 bot. The scenario I explained was for Virtual assistant bot so I am looking for that documentation or example.

Comment: Check my updated answer. I use the virtual assistant template and i followed that example to get User Interruption handling